# How can I move the products from a shop url to be displayed on the main menu of my homepage?

Tags: wordpress, redirect, plugins, woocommerce, product

I'm trying to find out how to move the products from

- http://bloomish.com/shop-bloomish url to
- the upper main menu displayed in my homepage, which is http://bloomish.com

I would appreciate any help for someone who barely understands code, this webpage wasn't created by me but at work they ask me to solve this issue and already asked to host gator free assistance, no results.

Thanks in advance.

PS: I'm using WooCommerce plugin to upload the products, the page was made using Wordpress.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Do you want to edit the menu so that the links will point to the shop-items? Looks like the current menu is set up that way but with the wrong links. Or do you need to transfer the entire shop to the main URL?

Comment: I need to link the product categories shown in my main menu at bloomish.com to be redirected to the products uploaded in the http://bloomish.com/shop-bloomish url, the entire shop needs to be able to be found in the main url

Comment: Am I correct in thinking these are two different wordpress installations? So there's wordpress on the main domain and another wordpress with woocommerce on /shop-bloomish?

Comment: No, it's only one wordpress installation. The webpage's domain used to be bloomish.com/bodycare, but I asked help to move it all to http://bloomish.com. It all seemed ok at first but when I explored the main menu categories the uploaded products at woo commerce plugin weren't showing anymore. I don't know why this error happened, the products used to show normally by clicking the menu's categories from the homepage, but then I discovered that they would only be found in the bloomish.com/shop-bloomish section and not menu as desired anymore.

Comment: Ok, I understand! When I look at the menu-items on the main site they seem to be missing shop-bloomish in it. For example the first item 'ducha' links to bloomish.com/ducha/ when it should be linking to bloomish.com/shop-bloomish/ducha/. Now I don't know where or how the menu is set up. Can you see the menu items in admin under view > menu's?

Comment: I'm sorry, with 'menu items' you are referring to the XMENU (plugin used to make the main menu) or something else?

Comment: Yes, even though I'm not sure why they have chosen to use a plugin for the menu this is probably where you can find an answer to the issue. If you login and go to the settings of this plugin you might be able to check the menu links.
It's hard for me to figure this out, some screenshots would help!